How do I install Steam games onto an external harddrive in SteamOS?
On Windows and other Linux distros, I simply go to Steam Storage Settings and add that external harddrive as a library storage device from here:

When I try to do it via the "Add Drive" option, then I get an error popup that says the following:

Failed to add Steam library folder



Why am I getting that error? How can I use my external harddrive and install games onto it?
The Drive itself is in perfect condition. I tested installing Steam games onto it with other operating systems. I tested on Windows 11, Linux Mint and Ubuntu. It worked on all of them, but on SteamOS, it doesn't want to work.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work or how I can get it to work?

I believe you cannot use a location pointing to the /run directory.  Unmount the drive from your Desktop Environment and mount it from a terminal.  See Answer

Issue
You cannot use the /run or /var/run as a location for permanent storage. See  Chapter 3. The Root Filesystem - 3.15. /run : Run-time variable data. By it's very nature run-time settings and data is volatile.
Fix
Mount the drive in a location that doesn't store volatile data. Example:
From a terminal as root:
mkdir -pv /mnt/steamStorage
mount -t fstype -v /dev/sdX /mnt/steamStorage

Be sure to replace fstype with the desired filetype and the letter X with the proper pointer/partition for the drive. After this point Steam to the location /mnt/steamStorage and update /etc/fstab so that the drive is automounted each boot, otherwise you'll need to recreate the mount point and add the drive each time you start Steam

What would be the "desired filetype" and "proper pointer/partition"? I just want whatever will work. There's no preference from my side. If I leave it the way you have it, would it work?

To figure out what's needed, plug the disk in and open it in a tool like Gparted or use lsblk.  The disk will have a Filesystem and a device descriptor.  For example your disk that Arch is installed on is most likely /dev/sda.  If the disk is partitioned then each partition is represented with a number, i.e. /dev/sda1 is the first partition on the a disk,  Each partition can contain a filesystem type,  The common ones are ext4 for linux, fat32 for most windows storage and USB and ntfs for the Windows drive itself.
